# SharePoint 2019 - Restore backup to new web app site

Tags: restore, iis

I have a test SharePoint 2019 Server with two web-app sites I will call Production and Development. URL for Production is https://production.foo.bar and the URL for development is https://development.foo.bar:3344.

I have a backup of the web-app site Development done via Central Administrator and restore tests back to Development work fine when overwriting.

What I want to do now is restore Development to Production without having to manually duplicate all the changes from Development to Production.

I tried restoring using the New Configuration restore type hoping that if i changed the fields to the Production site it would fix and the most i would need to due is possible update the IIS cert.  Nothing i tried so far has worked.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'New Configuration' restore type? I don't think it is feasible in scenario you are looking at. At least that wasn't possible in previous versions. Normally when you backup and restore you will overwrite the content. You cannot use backup and restore as an element of the SDLC lifecycle. In that respect SharePoint SDLC is a bit tricky. You need to develop the solution that you will deploy and activate in Production to make necessary changes to the structure of your artifacts and/or content.

Answer (score 0):

'New Configuration' restore type is the option used when Restoring the site collection development.foo.bar using Central Administration. Under the New Configuration setting it allows for creating a new name.

i actually found something that so far looks to be working
[back up restore onto a different site collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149790/back-up-restore-onto-a-different-site-collection)

i was able to take the dev site and back it up and restore it over the production site. Since all the links are relative so far so good minus a few titles that show dev that need manually updating.

Unsure at this point if anything else needs to be done though.